# how to make switch case click by array?

Tags: android, arrays

Please help me, how to make switch case click by array or how to make this switch case become if? because I have a searchbar, and when doing a search, the items that came out not in accordance with the array. for example when i clicking the item/array of es cendol, then the class shown is EsBerasKencur_ResepMinum.class, not EsCendol_ResepMinum.class. but the toast display showing items es cendol. please help me.

```
public class Dingin_Tab extends Activity implements
    OnItemClickListener {

public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Es Beras Kencur", "Dawet Ayu", 
    "Es Cendol", "Es Doger", "Es Oyen", "Es Teler", "Es Temulawak", 
    "Es Selendang Mayang", "Es Cincau", "Es Merah Delima"};

public static final Integer[] images = {R.drawable.minumberaskencur, 
    R.drawable.minumdawetayu, R.drawable.minumescendol,
    R.drawable.minumesdoger, R.drawable.minumesoyen, R.drawable.minumesteler, R.drawable.minumestemulawak, 
    R.drawable.minumesselendangmayang, R.drawable.minumescincau, R.drawable.minumesmerahdelima};

ListView listView;
List<RowItem> rowItems;
EditText editsearch;
ListView list;
CustomListViewAdapter madapter;
ArrayList<RowItem> arraylist = new ArrayList<RowItem>();



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listviewresma);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], null);
        rowItems.add(item);

    }

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_item, rowItems);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    madapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, 0, rowItems);

    // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
    listView.setAdapter(madapter);

    // Locate the EditText in listview_main.xml
    editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

    // Capture Text in EditText
    editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            madapter.filter(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

});
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:  Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(this, EsBerasKencur_ResepMinum.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity0);
            break;
        case 1:  Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(this, DawetAyu_ResepMinum.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity1);
            break;
        case 2:  Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(this, EsCendol_ResepMinum.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity2);
            break;
        case 3:  Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(this, EsDoger_ResepMinum.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity3);
            break;
        case 4:  Intent newActivity4 = new Intent(this, EsOyen_ResepMinum.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity4);
            break;
        case 5:  Intent newActivity5 = new Intent(this, EsTeler_ResepMinum.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity5);
            break;
        case 6:  Intent newActivity6 = new Intent(this, Temulawak_ResepMinum.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity6);
            break;
        case 7:  Intent newActivity7 = new Intent(this, EsSelendangmayang_ResepMinum.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity7);
            break;
        case 8:  Intent newActivity8 = new Intent(this, EsCincau_ResepMinum.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity8);
            break;
        case 9:  Intent newActivity9 = new Intent(this, EsMerahDelima_ResepMinum.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity9);
            break;
    }           
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Resep Minuman Dingin " + (position + 1) + ": " + rowItems.get(position),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug or log the position value? Also, you don't need to do things like this, you can have just a Intent declaration outside your switch and then just store the MyClass.class in a variable, then you will execute your code after the switch...I think is better to understand that way also

Comment: It could be that on Click is thrown for the other array, try to remove the other array items to test that the wrong position is because of the items array

Answer (score 0):

your filtered list is different from the `rowItems`, so check that which item you have clicked and which you are showing in toast. see this [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/)

Answer (score 0):

You donot need to use a switch case like this.There are multiple ways of achieving your required result.
One is that you can make the filtered list in your custom adapter as public and can get it by ists position from onItemClick().(filteredList.get(position))
Else you can add the class objectc as tag in your list adapter and get it inside onItemClick() as (view.getTag()).

Hope this helps.